# Can I use '>=' for NSComparisonResult?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to check that NSComparisonResult is less than or equal in `iOS`.

1.

```
NSComparisonResult result = blabla...;
if (result == NSOrderedAscending || result == NSOrderedSame) {...}
```

2.

```
NSComparisonResult result = blabla...;
if (result <= NSOrderedSame) {...}
```

I can use option 1, but, can I use option 2? I designed it because the `NSComparisonResult` is just `NSInteger`; `NSOrderedSame` is 0, `NSOrderedAscending` is -1, `NSOrderedDescending` is 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option 2 may work if you are careful. It's not clear what `<=` means versus `>=` so it is confusing. And it's far from ideal to make any assumptions about the `enum` values.

Option 3 is a better alternative:

```
NSComparisonResult result = ...
if (result != NSOrderedDescending) {
    // It's either ascending or same
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is better idea. Thank you.